# Joomla Cb Login Redirect Url Being Appended by Current Page

Tags: redirect, authentication, joomla

I have a joomla website and I use community builder for user registration and login.

I have a page with a url "http://localhost/joomla/index.php/page1" and I put a login module on that page. After login, I would like to redirect the user to "http://localhost/joomla/index.php/page2". So I set the Login Redirection URL field on the administration to "index.php/page2".

But my problem is, it redirects me to "http://localhost/joomla/index.php/page2/page1".
How am i able to just rediect it to page2 without appending the page1 on my url?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post seems similar:

http://www.joomlapolis.com/forum/146-general/192047-redirecting-after-login-using-cb-login-module

Does adding a forward slash to the beginning of you relative path help?

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution for CB auto login and redirect after registration if not need email check:
Edit: /components/com_comprofiler/comprofiler.php
There is a line around 1078:

```
    echo "\n<div>" . implode( "</div>\n<div>", $messagesToUser ) . "</div>\n";
```

Put this before (taken out from Login):

```
    //lets try to auto-login
    $app = &JFactory::getApplication();
```

`$password   =   cbGetParam( $_POST, 'password', '', _CB_ALLOWRAW );
    if($app->isSite())
    {
        # Login process
        $credentials = array(
            "username" => $username, 
            "password" => $password
        );

        if(is_dir(JPATH_BASE . DS . "components" . DS . "com_comprofiler")) {
            $database = &JFactory::getDBO();
            $sql_sync = "INSERT IGNORE INTO #__comprofiler(id, user_id) SELECT id,id FROM #__users";
            $database->setQuery($sql_sync);
            $database->query();
        }

        $app->login($credentials); 

        // Beside a redirection, writing out a text...
        global $mainframe;
        $mainframe->redirect(JRoute::_("<redirect-to-link>"),JText::_("You have logged in automatically."));
    }
    else {
        // This is just a redirection...
        global $mainframe;
        $mainframe->redirect(JRoute::_("<redirect-to-link>"));
    }`